# Why cannot superset connect to Athena using PyAthena and rest scheme and throws HTTP 422 "unexpected error"?

Tags: apache-superset

Installing Superset with `docker-compose`. App is up and running. When adding a new database using PyAthena connector, error `Unexpected error occurred, please check your logs for details` happens with no details in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are using `docker-compose`, check whether you have [added driver](https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/dockeradddrivers) to the build environment.

```
echo "PyAthena>1.2.0" >> ./docker/requirements-local.txt
```

If you don't you will get `Driver not found` error.

Second, check your URI scheme. It must be of the following form:

```
awsathena+rest://AKIAXXXX:XXXXXX@athena.{region}.amazonaws.com/{database_name}?s3_staging_dir=s3://{bucket_name_for_results}
```

If you are missing the query string part you may get mysterious error without a detail reason.

Also note that PyAthena [does not check you AK/SK against the staging bucket](https://pypi.org/project/pyathena/).